# Can all NOT IN statements be written with NOT EXISTS and JOIN? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I'm learning MySQL using SQLzoo, and I'm stuck on the following problem:

The table `'nobel'` looks something like this:

```
yr      subject     winner
1960    Chemistry   Willard F. Libby
1960    Literature  Saint-John Perse
1960    Medicine    Sir Frank Macfarlane Burnet
1960    Medicine    Peter Medawar
...
```

I'm trying to write a query that returns the following:

In which years was the Physics prize awarded but no Chemistry prize.

One way to write the query is to use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT yr FROM nobel WHERE subject = 'Physics' AND yr NOT IN (SELECT yr FROM nobel WHERE subject ='Chemistry')
```

How would I write it using `NOT EXIST` and `JOIN` statements?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I believe that all `not in` queries can be written using `not exists`.  In fact, it is better to use `not exists`, because it handles `NULL` values better than `not in`.

For your example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.yr
FROM nobel n
WHERE n.subject = 'Physics' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM nobel n2 WHERE n2.subject = 'Chemistry' and n2.yr = n.yr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the `OUTER JOIN` equivalent, although I prefer using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT N.yr 
FROM nobel n 
    LEFT JOIN nobel n2 on n.yr = n2.yr and n2.subject = 'Chemistry'
WHERE n2.yr IS NULL
    AND n.subject = 'Physics'
```